# Cant authenticate against JBoss Management Realm using CLI

Tags: xml, jboss, jboss7.x, command-line-interface, wildfly

I have setup a new JBoss server and am unable to access it remotely using 'jboss-cli.bat' due to authentication.  **However**, when I connect to the servers admin web console I am able to authenticate;

Through CLI I get the following error;

Unable to authenticate against controller at **.**.**.**:9999

This is after running 'connect **.**.**.**'

If I run the same command locally, I am able to conect.

I cannot locate any entries in the log with regard to this failed authentication.

I am running;

```
Windows Server 2008 R2
Wildfly 8.0.0 Alpha
```

My standalone.xml contains;

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="ManagementRealm">
        <any-ipv4-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="management">
        <any-ipv4-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-ipv4-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Could anyone put me on the right lines to solving this issue. Many thanks,

Stuart

Comment: You don't say if you have made any other changes to your configuration, I see you are using the word 'ManagementRealm' in the interfaces section - the security realms don't need to be referenced here so there could be some confusion in your configuration.  Also when executing the CLI you don't show any output so I can't tell if you are even being prompted for the username and password.

Comment: The decision was made to stop using Wildfly and to stay on 7.1

This worked on 7.1.

Sorry, Stu

Answer (score 3):

When you're using CLI you can authenticate using parameters `--user` and `--password`.

In my post-receive [git hook](https://gist.github.com/cilf/994c27c9e2ddd3348b9a) I ended up with

```
/opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --user=admin --password=yoursupersecretpassword --connect --command="deploy --force ROOT.war"
```

I got the idea from here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-2036

Answer (score 0):

I'm using redhat 7.6 and jboss 7.2 eap.
What I did was the following:
Delete from the standalone.xml.

```html
<authentication>
        <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/> --Delete line
        <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
</authentication>

<authentication>
       <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/> --Delete line
       <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
</authentication>
```

Bye.